# How to remove NaN values from corr() function output

Tags: python, pandas, correlation, dummy-variable

EDITED TO SHOW EXAMPLE OF ORIGINAL DATAFRAME:

```
df.head(4)

            shop   category  subcategory     season
date                
2013-09-04  abc    weddings  shoes           winter
2013-09-04  def    jewelry   watches         summer
2013-09-05  ghi    sports    sneakers        spring
2013-09-05  jkl    jewelry   necklaces       fall
```

I've successfully generated the following dataframe using get_dummies():

```
wedding_seasons = pd.get_dummies(df.loc[df['category']=='weddings',['category','season']],prefix = '', prefix_sep = '' )

wedding_seasons.head(3)

        weddings    winter  summer  spring  fall
71654   1.0         0.0     1.0     0.0     0.0
72168   1.0         0.0     1.0     0.0     0.0
72080   1.0         0.0     1.0     0.0     0.0
```

The goal of the above is to help assess frequency of weddings across seasons, so I've used `corr()` to generate the following result:

```
         weddings   fall       spring     summer       winter
weddings NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN          NaN
fall     NaN        1.000000   0.054019   -0.331866    -0.012122
spring   NaN        0.054019   1.000000   -0.857205    0.072420
summer   NaN        -0.331866  -0.857205  1.000000     -0.484578
winter   NaN        -0.012122  0.072420   -0.484578    1.000000
```

I'm unsure why the wedding column is generating NaN values, but my gut feeling is that it originates from how I originally created `wedding_seasons`. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated so that I can properly assess column correlations.

Comment: Does the value for `weddings` change ever? if it is constant then `.corr()` for that would always be `NaN`.

Comment: @HarvIpan that's a good point - I've edited my post above to show example rows of my original `df`. Looking at `wedding_seasons`, I feel the `loc()` function is what's only filtering `weddings` values when it really should be scanning every row and providing a 0 when the entry is something else than `weddings`. Thoughts?

Comment: You are creating dummies for `df.loc[df['category']=='weddings'` only. That is why your filtered data would always have wedding to be 1.

Comment: @HarvIpan that makes sense. is there a method to use `get_dummies()` to check all rows specifically for `weddings` in the `cateogry` column instead of just filtering rows with `weddings`?

Comment: Not sure, if I follow your question. May be ask another question? Not sure why you would like to find the correlation between 3 variables and with a constant variable. If you simply want to analyze the seasons and find which season contributes most, a bar chart would be sufficient.

Comment: @HarvIpan for example, my overall dataset shows highest frequency of weddings in the summer. I was able to determine this through barcharts. What I'd like to do is approach the same question of when weddings are most frequent in seasonal terms. If you take two example rows, where one shows a non-wedding value in the spring, and the second row shows a wedding value in the summer, then you can begin to build correlations. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you're interested in seeing here is the "correlation".

All of the columns in the dataframe `wedding_seasons` contain floating point values; however, if my suspicions are correct, the rows in your original dataframe `df` contain something like transaction records, where each row corresponds to an individual.

Please tell me if I'm incorrect, but I'll proceed with my reasoning.

Correlation will measure, intuitively, the tendency for values vary together/against each other within the same observation (e.g. if X and Y are negatively correlated, then when we see X go above its mean, we'd expect Y to appear below its mean).

However, what you have here is data where, if one transaction is `summer`, then categorically it cannot possibly be `winter` at the same time. When you create `wedding_seasons`, Pandas is creating dummy variables that are treated as floating point values when computing your correlation matrix; since it's impossible for any row to contain two `1.0` entries at the same time, clearly your resulting correlation matrix is going to have negative entries everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could drop the weddings column before doing `corr()`.

```
wedding_seasons.drop(columns = ['weddings'])
```

Comment: I want to keep the `weddings` column, but I don't want it just filtering `weddings` from the original `category` column. Idea is to use dummies to determine which among all rows have `weddings` as the input. This'll effectively let me draw correlations with season, otherwise it'll be `NaN`

Comment: I do not think answers the question. :(

Comment: I addressed the question of how to get rid of NaN. The idea was to drop the weddings column on a copy of the original df, and the copy would be used to figure out the correlations. I can delete the answer, no biggie.